# PHP exception with str_replace()

Tags: php, exception

Good day,

I got a little question.
Want to create a PHP exception to a str_replace function but I am seemling not able to do this.

```
    try {
        ///######## REPLACE THE PLACEHOLDERS
        $template   = str_replace($Source, $Target, $templateblocks[$file]);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

The above is my code.
Reason behind this is that in a certain itteration it throws a string to array error.
However when I add

```
if(is_array($templateblocks[$file]) === true){
echo 'an array set : print_r($templateblocks[$file], true).PHP_EOL.'<br /> file = '.$file);
}
```

This does not work. So I suggest adding an exception is going to solve this. But I am obviously missing something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `str_replace` doesn't throw exceptions or even any `Throwable`s

Comment: it's a `Notice` and it's `array to string conversion`. So you can do it with custom event handler only:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function does not throw any exceptions. You can only check your arguments (i.e. `$Source`, `$Target`, `$templateblocks`) and throw any Exception you want by yourself.

Example:

```
if(strllen($Source) > 10) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The source string is too long!');
}
```

And then eventually you can catch it inside `try {} catch(\InvalidArgumentException $e) {}`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's your problem actually. If I'm not wrong, you can't append your own code (exception) to basic PHP function.

But if you use PHP 7+, you could be able to catch \Throwable interface ([class.throwable.php](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php)) ??

**EDIT**:

My mistake, only errors throw Throwable. In that case the only way is to test your arguments before you use the function.